# Não consigo encontrar a diferença entre dois codigos

Tags: javascript, prompt, alert

Sou iniciante no javascript e recentemente eu estava cumprindo algumas aulas do curso. Um dos exercícios era de criar um formulário em html para aprender sobre objeto e método. Usei o código fonte do exercício proposto para me guiar e fiz um próprio, mas o resultado final do código não saiu de jeito nenhum

A proposta do código é criar uma biografia com os dados introduzidos (coisa boba).

Usei o código fonte do exercício proposto, formatando umas informações aqui e ali e no final eu consegui fazer a mesma proposta usando o código deles.

mas quando comparei os dois (o que deu errado e o que eu formatei pra dar certo), percebi que ERA APARENTEMENTE A MESMA COISA.

Eu não sei o que fazer. Faz umas 2 horas que eu tô aqui parado, estudando essee código e nada de conseguir entender.

CODIGO ERRADO:

```html
    <form name="respostas" action="" method="post">
        <!-- ESTRUTURA PARA RECEBER OS DADOS -->
        <!-- type: tipo de entrada / name: nome para localizar -->
    Digite seu nome.........: <input type="text" name="nome"><br>
    Digite seu sobrenome....: <input type="text" name="sobrenome"><br>
    Digite sua idade........: <input type="text" name="idade"><br>
    Digite sua cidade.......: <input type="text" name="cidade"><br>
    Digite sua função no seu trabalho: <input type="text" name="funcao"><br>
    <!-- servirá para cancelar ou prosseguir -->
    <input type="button" name="btn-concatena" value="Crie sua biografia!" onclick="concatena()">
    <input type="reset" name="btn-apagar" value="Reinicie" >
    </form>

    <script>
        var nome
        var sobrenome
        var idade
        var cidade
        var funcao
        var bio
        function concatena() {
            /* entrada de dados */
            nome = document.respostas.nome.value;
            sobrenome = document.respostas.sobrenome.value;
            idade = document.respostas.idade.value;
            cidade = document.respostas.cidade.value;
            funcao = document.respostas.funcao.value;
            /* processamento */
            bio = 'Me chamo ' + nome + ' ' + sobrenome + ',' + 'tenho ' + idade + 'anos' + ',' + 'moro em ' + cidade + 'e trabalho na função de ' + função + '.';
            /* saída */
            window.alert('Aqui está sua biografia: ' + bio);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CODIGO QUE DEU CERTO

```html
    <form name="respostas" action="" method="post">
        <!-- ESTRUTURA PARA RECEBER OS DADOS -->
        <!-- type: tipo de entrada / name: nome para localizar -->
    Digite seu nome.........: <input type="text" name="nome"><br>
    Digite seu sobrenome....: <input type="text" name="sobrenome"><br>
    Digite sua idade........: <input type="text" name="idade"><br>
    Digite sua cidade.......: <input type="text" name="cidade"><br>
    Digite sua função no seu trabalho: <input type="text" name="funcao"><br>
    <!-- servirá para cancelar ou prosseguir -->
    <input type="button" name="btn-concatena" value="Crie sua biografia!" onclick="concatena()">
    <input type="reset" name="btn-apagar" value="Reinicie" >
    </form>

    <script>
        var nome
        var sobrenome
        var idade
        var cidade
        var funcao
        var bio
        
        function concatena() {
            
            /* ENTRADA DE DADOS */
            nome = document.respostas.nome.value;
            sobrenome = document.respostas.sobrenome.value;
            idade = document.respostas.idade.value;
            cidade = document.respostas.cidade.value;
            função = document.respostas.funcao.value;
            /* processamento */
            bio = 'Me chamo ' + nome + ' ' + sobrenome + ',' + 'tenho ' + idade + 'anos' + ',' + 'moro em ' + cidade + 'e trabalho na função de ' + função + '.';
            /* saída */
            window.alert('Aqui está sua biografia: ' + bio);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O primeiro código falha porque ao montar a `bio` vc usa a variável `função` (com cedilha e acento), mas essa variável não existe (repare que vc criou a variável `funcao` - sem cedilha nem acento). O segundo código funciona pq ali foi criada a variável correta, a mesma usada para montar a `bio` (mas o primeiro funcionaria se vc usasse `funcao` - sem acento - para criar a `bio`, [veja aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/qfz8x4dt/)). **O problema é só esse, mero erro de digitação**. Toda a explicação dada na [resposta abaixo](/a/568172/112052) está completamente errada e diz coisas sem sentido.

Comment: Ex: "*usa a variavel "Funcao" para forma a função de resposta e repete a mesma variavél 2 vezes*" (errado, não "repete" a variável), "*Não se usa o nome de uma variavél para chamar uma função mais sim para forma a função*" (errado, não tem nada a ver com chamar função - e nem com "formar" função, seja lá o que isso quer dizer), e por fim "*usando variavel para expressar uma função ou se alto corresponde-la*" e "*Uma palavra em uma variavel é reservada para forma função, então ela não pode ser usada de maneira "Expressiva" dessa maneira que a usou*" (essas frases não fazem o menor sentido).

Comment: Ou seja, **o único problema foi o erro de digitação**, toda a explicação da outra resposta está sem sentido e não diz nada com nada. Desculpe se estou parecendo rude, mas é que a ideia do site é servir de referência para futuros visitantes, então é importante apontar os problemas quando eles existem (e o fato da resposta ter sido marcada como "correta" torna tudo mais grave ainda, pois um usuário iniciante e desavisado pode acabar achando que aquilo faz sentido). Enfim, a explicação é  que vc tentou usar uma variável que não existia, e se usasse a variável correta tudo funcionaria. Só isso.

Comment: E só pra completar, não tem motivo pra criar as variáveis fora da função `concatena`, faça tudo dentro dela. Algo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/3w8jpL7e/

Answer (score -4, accepted):

**Opa amigo tudo bem ?**

O seu erro é bem simples.

**var funcao**

**funcao = document.respostas.funcao.value; (Oque não deu certo!)**

(Repare que aqui você usa a variavel "Funcao" para forma a função de resposta e repete a mesma **variavél 2** vezes)

**1° funcao** < Variavel = document.respostas.**funcao 2°**

**1° Função** < Não Variavel = document.respostas.funcao.value; **(Qual é o proximo problema ? kkk pq esse ta solucionado.)**

Não se usa o nome de uma variavél para chamar uma função mais sim para forma a função.

Quando você mudou para:
**função = document.respostas.funcao.value; (Oque deu Certo!)**
Funcionou porque você não está usando uma variavel como "Expressão" mais sim ta usando uma sem valor uma palavra não variavel que pode ser expressa a qualquer momento.

**Uma palavra em uma variavel é reservada para forma função, então ela não pode ser usada de maneira "Expressiva" dessa maneira que a usou.**

Se você pega o código que funcionou e troca o **"Função por Funcao"** repare que não vai funcionar o código que esta funcionando porque você esta usando variavel para expressar uma função ou se alto corresponde-la.

Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Veja [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/137387) e [Saudações e Agradecimentos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/137387).

Answer (score -2):

Em um você escreveu funcao, e no outro função.

```js
funcao = document.respostas.funcao.value
```

```js
função = document.respostas.funcao.value
```